# How to instantiate and extend Python igraph Vertex class

Tags: python, inheritance, igraph, instantiation, vertex

I'd like to extend the igraph Vertex class with some extra variables methods I need for a simulation study. However, when I try to import and extend the vertex class, I get an error.

```
from igraph import Vertex

v = Vertex()
```

> TypeError: cannot create 'igraph.Vertex' instances

Likewise, the same error occurs when I try to extend the class.

```
from igraph import Vertex

class MyVertex(Vertex):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

my_vertex = MyVertex()
```

> TypeError: cannot create 'MyVertex' instances

**How can I instantiate igraph vertices and extend the igraph Vertex class?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vertex` instances are not meant to be instantiated; this is intentional. A `Vertex` is simply a wrapper around a reference to a graph and a vertex index, and it provides a few convenience methods that are usually just proxies to the same method on the associated graph instance. Even if you created your own `Vertex` subclass, there is currently no way to tell an igraph `Graph` object to start returning your `Vertex` subclass for expressions like `graph.vs[x]` instead of `Vertex` itself.

If you want to create your own vertex-like classes, you can try composition instead of inheritance, i.e. you create a `MyVertex` class that takes a `Vertex` as its constructor argument, stores the vertex and then forwards method calls to it, depending on what you need to support in your own `MyVertex` instance:

```py
class MyVertex:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self._v = v

    def degree(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._v.degree(*args, **kwds)
    
    ...
```

Note that since `Vertex` instances are simply wrappers for a graph and a vertex ID, things can get confusing if you remove vertices from a graph because the remaining vertices are re-indexed by the underlying C library to ensure that their IDs are always in the range [0; n-1] for n vertices.